# Synaptic Clickpad not working while typing on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, hp-pavilion

In 2015 I bought an HP Pavilion (if specs are needed I will put them as an edit), and ever since I got it home, I can't move the mouse pointer using the touch pad (ClickPad - whole pad is a button) while gaming or just after typing.  I have searched everywhere.

[This Microsot Community post](https://goo.gl/u24S6J) dose not work because my PC settings don't look the same as they explain.

The pics half way down in [this forum post](https://goo.gl/XCwLsn) don't look the same as on my PC.

I have looked all over the internet also on Windows and HP's own forums and sites.

Pics of the options i have on my PC:
[image: Here]

Hope some of you guys can help me!

Comment: Do you have the ASUS Windows 10 drivers installed or the generic Synaptic drivers installed?

Answer (score 0):

I would have assumed the settings you're looking for would have been under the `ClickPad Settings` button in your first screen shot like your links suggest ("Palm check" or "SmartSense").

Have you tried installing the latest Synaptic drivers from [here](http://www.synaptics.com/resources#drivers) and see if they have an option to disable it?